# CS0103. The name 'Functions' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm am stuck on this Lua executer I am working on. It uses an API and a few stuff, but shouldn't be that confusing. I am a beginner in C#, and I need a little help on a problem I am having. I am getting an error: CS0103. The name 'Functions' does not  exist in the current context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WeAreDevs_API

;
namespace Supreme_Executer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ExploitAPI api = new ExploitAPI();
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = fastColoredTextBox1.Text;
            this.api.SendLuaScript(text);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fastColoredTextBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opendialogfile = new OpenFileDialog();
            opendialogfile.Filter = "Lua File (*.lua)|*.lua|Text File (*.txt)|*.txt";
            opendialogfile.FilterIndex = 2;
            opendialogfile.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (opendialogfile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                return;
            try
            {
                fastColoredTextBox1.Text = "";
                System.IO.Stream stream;
                if ((stream = opendialogfile.OpenFile()) == null)
                    return;
                using (stream)
                    this.fastColoredTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(opendialogfile.FileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int num = (int)MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occured", "oof lmao", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.Left += e.X - lastPoint.X;
                this.Top += e.Y - lastPoint.Y;
            }
        }
        Point lastPoint;

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => fastColoredTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText($"./Scripts/{listBox1.SelectedItem}");

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();//Clear Items in the LuaScriptList
            Functions.PopulateListBox(listBox1, "./Scripts", "*.txt");
            Functions.PopulateListBox(listBox1, "./Scripts", "*.lua");
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If you want to download the Visual Studio solution to view it better, [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/jhfxn5z64lvimwz/Executer.zip/file)

Comment: It's rather self-explanatory... Where is `Functions` declared? Is it class? Is it static? Or maybe it's just random text considered to magically work?

Comment: I'm voting to close because the issue appears to be caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution doesn't have `Functions` class but `Function` class exists.

Change your code like this :

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();//Clear Items in the LuaScriptList
        Function.PopulateListBox(listBox1, "./Scripts", "*.txt");
        Function.PopulateListBox(listBox1, "./Scripts", "*.lua");
    }
```

Comment: thanks! it was totally a typo!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you are either missing `using` statement importing namespace with `Functions`. Look up `Functions` and add it's namespace at the start of your file.